# Can FEMM be used to calculate real power of a PMSM at 50Hz frequency?

Tags: power, frequency, analysis, pmsm, femm

I am working with FEMM, for past few months and i have this doubt that can real power of a PMSM be calculated using FEMM at 50Hz frequency?..
Because at frequency higher than 0Hz the flux produced by permanent magnet is neglected.. as pm are assumed as current carrying electromagnets of 0Hz frequency. And FEMM can't do fea analysis for materials that contain 2 different frequencies.
It just neglects the 0Hz frequency part.
So how can i calculate the power of the motor i designed at 50Hz frequency!?
Please answer this question!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Is the applied voltage a sinewave?

Comment: yes Mr.@Andyaka

Answer (score 0):

> *Can FEMM be used to calculate real power of a PMSM at 50Hz frequency?*

We're talking about real power and if this is true: -

```
Is the applied voltage a sinewave? – Andy aka
```

> *yes Mr.@Andyaka – Mohammed Siddique*

And, apparently it is,

Then, to calculate real power you only need to do that at the fundamental frequency. Any currents that are at harmonics of the basic fundamental sinewave voltage frequency (due to distortion) do not contribute towards the real power consumed.

Comment: The results shown by FEMM at fundamental frequency, Is the values are true? because the result doesn't show any flux passing through the magnet as the "magnet's frequency is 0, or the software assumes it as that". please explain me based on how "FEMM" works for PMSM at frequencies other than zero Mr.@Andyaka

Comment: A DC supply and a sine current produce no average heating power. A sine of 1 frequency and a sine of an uncorrelated frequency produce no average heating power. You can't have heating power from harmonics when the applied signal is a sine. It's a mathematical impossibility. That is why I asked you if the applied voltage is a sine wave @MohammedSiddique. With an applied sinewave, only the fundamental frequency of the current waveform produces a heating power in the load irrespective of how distorted the current waveform is. This applies to all types of signals, not just voltage and current.

Comment: Sir @Andyaka, the applied voltage is of sine form there's no problem with that. The problem is HOW "FEMM - The FEA Analysis software works with it? " Please look into FEMM and answer this question sir. And please answer the question I've been searching this answer for days.